# is_page_template() written in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

With php there is a wordpress function is_page_template()

Is there a similar function written in jquery/javascript?

To use with the `wp.customize` api and jquery/javascript.

Comment: Did you try to use the body classes? They are different for the different templates.

Comment: In the customizer or in the preview? If you want to conditionally show customizer controls based this is already supported with the `active_callback` argument for `add_control()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, in WordPress, different templates have a different body class name. If you inspect the body classes on a specific page in WordPress, there should be a body class `page`. You can detect the template by checking if the class exists like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ( $('body').hasClass('page')) {
        // add your logic here
    }
});
```